# How to vectorize operations in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Patient':['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8', 'p8', 'p10'],
                   'S1':[0.7, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9, 0.2, 0.6, 0.3],
                   'S2':[0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9, 0.7, 0.4, 0.3],
                   'S3':[0.6, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.3, 0.6, 0.3],
                   'S4':[0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9, 0.7, 0.3, 0.3 ],
                   'S5':[0.9, 0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.7, 0.2, 0.7, 0.6, 0.3 ]})

# vectorized operations in data frame

# get the number of the cells that are >=0.5 for each column
arr1 = df[columns].ge(0.5).sum().to_numpy()

# get the sum the cells that are >=0.5 for each column
arr2 = df[df[columns]>=0.5][columns].sum().to_numpy()

print(arr1)
print(arr2)
```

How do I get the list of patients or a set of patients for each column in the df like below?

```
[('p1', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p7', 'p9'), 
 ('p3', 'p5', 'p7', 'p8'), 
 ('p1', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p9'), 
 (...),
 (...)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not tabular format. You can just use a list comprehension in this case:

```
[df.Patient[df[col] >= 0.5].to_list() for col in columns]

#[['p1', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p7', 'p8'],
# ['p3', 'p5', 'p7', 'p8'],
# ['p1', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8'],
# ['p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p7', 'p8'],
# ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p8', 'p8']]
```

Comment: Thanks @Psidom. With list comprehension will it be a vectorized operation? Wouldn't be same as looking at each column separately?

Comment: It's partially vectorized. The per column filtering is still vectorized - I don't think you can vectorize everything here since the result is not in tabular format.

Comment: *Wouldn't be same as looking at each column separately?*
Yes it is, but normally that's enough since the number of columns is usually small, so you want to vectorize the dimension that's large, i.e. `rows` in this case.

Comment: This was the more understandable answer for me. I wish it were vectorized for both rows and columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible option :

```
ss = (df.set_index("Patient").ge(0.5)
          .groupby(level=0, sort=False).max())

out = (ss.T @ (ss.index + ",")).str[:-1]
```

Output (*with two different formats*):

```
>>> out.str.split(",").to_list()

[['p1', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p7', 'p8'],
 ['p3', 'p5', 'p7', 'p8'],
 ['p1', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8'],
 ['p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p7', 'p8'],
 ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p8']]

>>> out.str.split(",").to_dict()

{'S1': ['p1', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p7', 'p8'],
 'S2': ['p3', 'p5', 'p7', 'p8'],
 'S3': ['p1', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8'],
 'S4': ['p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p7', 'p8'],
 'S5': ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p8']}
```

How it works ?

First, we make a boolean DataFrame using [`ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) (+[`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) *to handle potential duplicates*) :

```
Patient p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p10
S1       x     x  x  x     x  x    
S2             x     x     x  x    
S3       x     x  x  x  x  x  x    
S4             x  x  x     x  x    
S5       x  x  x  x  x  x     x    

[5 rows x 9 columns]
```

Then, we compute a matrix multiplication (*using* [`dot/@`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html#pandas.DataFrame.dot)):

```
S1       p1,p3,p4,p5,p7,p8
S2             p3,p5,p7,p8
S3    p1,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8
S4          p3,p4,p5,p7,p8
S5    p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p8
```

And at the end, we [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and use [`to_list`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_list.html) (*or* [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html)) to get the expected format.

Comment: Thanks @Timeless. Can you explain how it works? And since there is no for loop, does it mean that it is vectorized for columns and rows at the same time?

Comment: Is the walrus operator _really_ necessary to accomplish this?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark, no.

Comment: @burcak, you're welcome, I added the intermediates to make it a bit clearer ;).

Comment: I'd suggest not using it. It really makes it hard to understand. We're not playing golf here. :)

Comment: It writes that the walrus operator is introduced in Python 3.8. This might be a restriction. What about patients can be repeated at the rows, can we get unique patients?

Comment: @burcak, I updated the answer to handle duplicated patients.

Comment: @Timeless thanks for your answers. Where are the columns in the first statement? I got "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'".

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [tuple(df.loc[df[col] >= 0.5, 'Patient']) for col in columns]
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**